# Regular expression to extract Facebook URL's inc vanity

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract Facebook URL's from 3 sites using PHP and a regular expression but it's not working for me. I can use regex101 https://regex101.com/r/zA2sD8/1 to match but i can't get this out in PHP using preg_match. Here is my regex so far:

https://regex101.com/r/zA2sD8/1

Comment: Did you use preg_match or preg_match_all?

Comment: Did you use delimiters? Can you show your current code usage? You can simplify `http|https` into `https?`.

Comment: Seems to be working for me: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/y0tq-g5hh

Comment: Its not working because what you're trying to capture with this `([\w-]*)?` does not include punctuation in the class. So, it stops short of matching `www.facebook.com/another`.test .. Also, everything after the domain is optional in the regex, why so detailed with the literal's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following pattern:

```
((?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?facebook\.com\S*)
```

of course, you'll have to use a different delimiter than `/` (like `@` or `#` etc.).

You'll also need to use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match` to imitate the global matching (`g` flag).